# Sort text file with delimiter

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file that is 800KB line by line with comma delimiter.
I am trying to sort this text file by the first part which is a date.
when I run this it takes about 2 seconds to complete.
something is really slowing it down, what do you guys see?

```
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Dim sMilli As Integer = 1000
    Dim iSortedDates As New SortedDictionary(Of Date, String)
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(iFilePath)
        Dim eachPart() As String = line.Split(","c)
        Dim eachDate As Date = Date.Parse(eachPart(0)).AddMilliseconds(sMilli)
        iSortedDates(eachDate) = line
        If sMilli = 5000 Then sMilli = 1
        sMilli += 1
    Next
    Dim iAllData As String = ""
    For Each iSNew In iSortedDates.Keys
        iAllData += iSortedDates(iSNew) & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & iFilePath, iAllData)
    sw.Stop()
    Debug.Print("Total Milliseconds: " & sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
```

Comment: 800kb doesn't say much. you can squeeze 400,000 lines of "x\n" into that file, in which case sorting 400,000 lines in 2 seconds isn't all that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting version 4 or higher of the Framework, you may be able to save some time by using `IO.File.ReadLines` instead of `IO.File.ReadAllLines` as `ReadLines` doesn't make you wait until the whole file is read before you can start processing the lines.

You can avoid building that long `iAllData` string one line at a time by using `iSortedDates.Values` to create an array that can be written bi `IO.File.WriteAllLines`.

```
Dim sw As New Stopwatch
sw.Start()
Dim sMilli As Integer = 1000
Dim iSortedDates As New SortedDictionary(Of Date, String)
For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines(iFilePath)
    Dim eachPart() As String = line.Split(","c)
    Dim eachDate As Date = Date.Parse(eachPart(0)).AddMilliseconds(sMilli)
    iSortedDates(eachDate) = line
    If sMilli = 5000 Then sMilli = 1
    sMilli += 1
Next
Dim iAllData() As String = iSortedDates.Values.ToArray 
IO.File.WriteAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & iFilePath, iAllData)
sw.Stop()
Debug.Print("Total Milliseconds: " & sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look into `Linq` if you could. Below is a quick query I have done for you, it not only reads all of the lines, but it **checks if the split string is a date** then order by that and put anything else at the end sorted. I tested this on a **6.73 MB** file and came out at **1.97** seconds. If you ask me that is really quick I would say.

**You can use this anywhere**

```
  Dim nDate As Date
  Dim lines As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(yourfile).Where(Function(x) Date.TryParse(x.Split(","c)(0), nDate) OrElse Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).OrderBy(Function(line) line.Split(",")(0)).ToList

  IO.File.WriteAllText("FILE LOCATION", Concat(lines))
```

**Function to return all lines in a string**

```
Public Shared Function Concat(source As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each s As String In source
        sb.AppendLine(s)
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

**P.S.** Sorry if the `Linq` query looks long, you can make that top down so it can be easier to read if you want.